# Load Controller from View in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

As an example I use an controller called "Akun"

```
package myipaymu

class AkunController {    
    def index() {}
    def profil() {}
}
```

In my view I want to load "profil" action just like iframe in html, but not iframe.

```
---------------------------------------
|          index                      |
|                                     |
|     ---------------------------     |
|     | profil                  |     |
|     |                         |     |
|     --------------------------      |
---------------------------------------
```

I think I can use `<g:` but I don't really understand how it works. can any one help me? Or suggest where I can find the tutorial??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to include the response from the `profil` controller action within a GSP? The easiest way to do this is with the [g:include](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html) tag, e.g.

```
---------------------------------------
|          index                      |
|                                     |
| ---------------------------------   |
| | <g:include action="profil"/>  |   |
| |                               |   |
| ---------------------------------   |
---------------------------------------
```